# iOS - Bundle app with text file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a .json file that I want to be bundled with my application as a resource. I've read the [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) which says that you should put support files in the `<Application_Home>/Library/Application Support`. So how do I put my .json file in this directory before building my application?

And how would I reference the file during runtime?

Comment: Is this meant to be a read-only file at runtime or will you need to update the file?

Comment: I will occasionally need to update the file (once a year or so).

Comment: Will the update be done in the app at runtime or as part of an app update?

Comment: I suppose the most convenient way for the user would be to have this file updated by downloading it when a new version is available, but for now I think I will include it as an app update. But I would like to know how to support both scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file will always be read-only (only updated as part of an app update), then add the file to your app's resources in your project. Then you simply read the file from the app's bundle:

```
// assume a filename of file.txt. Update as needed
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"];
```

If you need to provide an initial file with your app but make updates during runtime then you need to package the file like above, but the first time your app is run you need to copy the file to another, writable location in your app's sandbox.

```
// Get the Application Support directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appSupportDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// Create this path in the app sandbox (it doesn't exist by default)
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:appSupportDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

// Copy the file from the app bundle to the application support directory
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *newPath = [appSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePath lastPathComponent]];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:newPath error:nil];
```

Comment: So it's only possible to write to the Application Support directory during runtime?

Comment: Yes. The app sandbox isn't created until the app is installed on a user's device. You can only put files in the bundle at app build time.

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation here http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/finding-or-creating-application-support.html

The directory would need to created at run time, and files moved there from your main bundle, then you can access them using the methods described in the link.

Comment: I am referring to the File System Programming Guide which does have information about iOS apps (not only MacOS). And there is most definately a file system for iOS apps (that you can read about in the guide).